# Is there a way to render json data in order based on the data?

Tags: javascript, json, ejs

**So My question is:**

- Can I **render** the items below in an **order based on** the **"price" value** ascending / descending or perhaps the alphabetical value of "name" and not just in the order that the code is placed.

Another question if you're feeling extra helpful ;)

- Is it possible to apply maths to json number values. Say I wish to multiply all "price" values by 2 how can I do this?
- Many thanks for any help, greatly appreciated :D

**My Json File Example**

```
{

 "item1": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Item1",
  "price": 50,
   }
 ],

"item2": [
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Item2",
  "price": 15,
}
 ],

"item3": [
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Item 3",
  "price": 10,
  }
  ]
}
```

**Here is my rendering of the data using EJS:**

Item 1:

```
<section class="container content-section">
    <% items.item1.forEach(function(item){ %>
    
    <div class="shop-item" data-item-id="<%= item.id %>">
    
    <span class="shop-item-title"> <%= item.name %></span> </a>
         
    <span class="shop-item-price">$<%= item.price / 100 %></span>

    </section>
    <% }) %>
```

Item 2:

```
<section class="container content-section">
    <% items.item2.forEach(function(item){ %>
    
    <div class="shop-item" data-item-id="<%= item.id %>">
    
    <span class="shop-item-title"> <%= item.name %></span> </a>
         
    <span class="shop-item-price">$<%= item.price / 100 %></span>

    </section>
    <% }) %>
```

Item 3:

```
<section class="container content-section">
    <% items.item3.forEach(function(item){ %>
    
    <div class="shop-item" data-item-id="<%= item.id %>">
    
    <span class="shop-item-title"> <%= item.name %></span> </a>
         
    <span class="shop-item-price">$<%= item.price / 100 %></span>

    </section>
    <% }) %>
```

Comment: not in ejs, because its rendered serverside. But you can use clientside js to reorder the dom or data, or make ajax call to an endpoint with sorting.

Comment: `<% items.item1.sort((a, b) => (a.price > b.price) ? 1 : -1).map(i => i.price * 2).forEach(function (item) { %>`